# Could potatoes that have been refrigerated for 142 days still sprout?

Tags: seeds

I know that potatoes can still sprout even after being refrigerated, but could you refrigerate them for 142 days still use them as seeds to grow more plants after that?

As for the temperature of the fridge, [look at this.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126410/potatoes-were-alive-and-sprouted-on-mars-how-were-they-preserved-on-the-journey)
 Considering that, what would be likely?

What about frozen or hermetic potatoes?

If anyone's wondering why I'm asking such a strange question, [here's why.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126410/potatoes-were-alive-and-sprouted-on-mars-how-were-they-preserved-on-the-journey)

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [gardening.se].

Comment: It would also be better if you can specify what range of temperature you are talking about. By fridged, you mean ~4⁰C?

Comment: @WYSIWYG I updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is very common to do this on farms. I have grown potatoes that I stored loosely in my basement (~5 degree temperature during the winter when they would be stored) for about 6 months at a time every year for the past 20 years.